# Access Denied when using a remote machine local user account

Tags: remote

As a team . we need to drop files into a specific folder on another machine , a server,  on same network & domain to perform some automation work

Created a local user  with  admin  access on server . Shared the credentials to all users to map that server folder on their individual machines
. 
Tried to connect as  \< server hostname>\c$  as a  mapped drive from user's machine
Gave "\" and password to connect as mapped drive
Get Access denied while trying to connect to that folder as mapped drive.
As there too many users , all cannot be added as users in server and as part of company domain the registry settings are not accessible to users

All machines are on Windows 10

any help ??

Thanks

Comment: This is by design - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/951016/description-of-user-account-control-and-remote-restrictions-in-windows

Comment: Microsoft "remote desktop" app is able to connect to remote machine using the same local use credentials . How are they doing it ? I am sure they are not disabling UAC to do it .

Answer (score 1):

> Created a local user with admin access on server. Shared the credentials to all users to map that server folder on their individual machines.

I would suggest that this is a [fairly] Bad Idea. 
OK, it's not the *worst* idea in the World by any means, but definitely towards the "red end" of the Risk scale.

Using the Hidden Administrative shares is not a Good Idea.
These shares are not visible to those End Users who know enough to be able to "browse" to the machine itself.  Believe me, they *will* complain about this.

Giving out Administrative credentials for a server to End Users *is* a [really] Bad Idea.

- Create a regular, shared directory.
  If you want it to stay hidden, append "$" to the Share name but, as
  above, I would suggest this is not ideal ("Security through
  Obscurity" is rarely effective).
- Create a Domain Group to hold the Users who should have access to this Share.
  If you *really* want to allow Everyone access to it, then you can use "Everyone", but I would question this as well.  What is the *purpose* of this file share?  For what will it be used?
- Grant permissions on the Share *and* the underlying Directory to that Group.

> ... the registry settings are not accessible ...

Assuming you mean the *Windows* Registry ...

Why are End Users doing *anything* with [Windows] Registry settings??
This is especially critical because, armed with their current, *Administrative* credentials, that can basically *destroy* the server.

I think you need to take some time and reevaluate what you're trying to achieve.

Ask yourself: What [Business] Problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: HI Phil, Sharing of folder is barred on network. The only other way I know of accessing the remote folder is using C$. is there any other way ?

Comment: By whom has sharing been "banned"?  It seems to me that you have a legitimate reason to use it here so go and negotiate with them.  Anything else you do is just trying to "get around" the security model that's in place and that's likely to land you in hot water.